Cylinder about diameter in hyperbolic space is convex
Suppose $B^n$ is the Poincare model of the hyperbolic ball, and $L$ is a diameter. Let $C$ be a Euclidean cylinder of radius $r$ about the axis $L$. If the endpoints of a geodesic lie in $C$, I'd like to show that the entire geodesic lies in $C$.
This is claimed in a proof in Ratcliffe. I tried a strategy based on parametrizing a geodesic (circle orthogonal to $B^n$) and then showing that distance to $L$ is a convex function, but the algebra gets messy and I was hoping for a slicker solution.

I now have a messy algebra solution in the vein of what I described, but would still be happy to see a cleaner solution.
